# error use of undeclared identifier webview

Tags: ios, objective-c

> i had this error "use of undeclared identifier 'webview ' " in viewcontroller.m . also i need to call html page from file "www" .

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *localFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www/index" ofType:@"html"] ;
    NSURLRequest *localRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath]] ;

    [webView loadRequest:localRequest] ;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView1;

@end
```

Comment: you try to access an instance variable named `webView`. However, you only have a property named `WebView1`. That won't work, read your error messages and don't rely on Stackoverflow Driven Development. Also you should ditch iOS 4 and use weak instead of assign in your properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this line in your **.h** file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView1;
```

write this line in your **.m** file

```
@synthesize WebView1;
```

Comment: thanks it worked now but what about www/index . is i added the right path ? as i want to call html file from www

Comment: i have this error when deploy " no visible @interface for 'NSBundle' declares the selector 'pathfor request ...'